# Array columns comparison on SparkSQL / Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I had the following query:

`SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.a = 10 AND t2.a > 20 AND t1.b=t2.b`

The application evolved to having `t1.a`, `t2.a`, `t1.b` and `t2.b` arrays.

I could rewrite `t1.a = 10` to `array_contains(t1.a, 10)`, but I couldn't find any valid supported SQL features that enable me to reproduce the logical comparison `t2.a > 20` and column intra-tables comparison `t1.b=t2.b` effect on arrays.

Could anyone help me with rewriting the query? does it possibly require a user defined function?

Context: I'm using Spark SQL to query Parquet tables. I included Hive tag as Spark SQL implements many of its functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `UDF` to do the comparison. Pretty easy:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("arrayGreater", (arr: Seq[Int], x: Int) => {
   arr.toArray.filter(i => i > x).length > 0
})
```

And then, you use it like this:

```
val df = Seq((1,Array(1,2,3)), (2,Array(7,9,11))).toDF("key", "arr")
df.registerTempTable("DF")

df.show
+---+----------+
|key|       arr|
+---+----------+
|  1| [1, 2, 3]|
|  2|[7, 9, 11]|
+---+----------+

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from DF where arrayGreater(arr, 10)").show
+---+----------+
|key|       arr|
+---+----------+
|  2|[7, 9, 11]|
+---+----------+
```

Note that as of right now, `arrayGreater` is returning a `Boolean`. You could make it return an `Int` -- simply return the filtered `length` instead of checking if it is `> 0`:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("arrayCountGreater", (arr: Seq[Int], x: Int) => {
   arr.toArray.filter(i => i > x).length
})

sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, arrayCountGreater(arr, 2) from DF").show
+---+----------+-----+
|key|       arr|count|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1| [1, 2, 3]|    1|
|  2|[7, 9, 11]|    3|
+---+----------+-----+
```